# #Error while RDLC Summing with Empty Values

Tags: mysql, vb.net, sum, rdlc

I'm facing issues with RDLC report when performing **Sum** of particular Columns that does not returning values. Only showing #error.

This is my MySQL View that i created:

[image]

Select Query:

[image]

RDLC report I created:

[image]

Report generated with VB.Net but I am facing this below issue:

[image]

I've tried all the RDLC expressions by Googling but they are not working.

```
=Sum(CDbl(Fields!Sales.Value))

=Sum(IIF(Fields!Sales.Value = "", Fields!Sales.Value, 0))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like your condition is wrong:

```
Sum(IIF(Fields!Sales.Value != "", Fields!Sales.Value, 0))
```

more convenient:

```
Sum(IIF(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Fields!Sales.Value), Fields!Sales.Value, 0))
```

if Above is not working , you can change your query as well:
 add case in sql query.

Let me know if you need help for query change.